# Passing array in function in UFT

Tags: automation, hp-uft

I am trying to pass the array name in a function such that it should do some action based on the mentioned array name only. But I am getting error as Type Mismatch.

```
Dim oFormPage()
Function GEN_FormLabelCheck(oModuleName,oFormPage)

        Select Case oModuleName
            Case "AA"
                lableList=split("Scenario|Name|Event,"|")
            Case "BB"
                lableList=split("ID|Issue|mandatory?,"|")
            Case "CC"
                lableList_01=split("Name","|")
                lableList_02=split("Work|Category|Type","|")
        End Select
msgbox UBound(oFormPage)

Call GEN_FormLabelCheck("CC",lableList_02)
```

Please suggest where I am making mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the type mismatch error because you are trying to `msgbox` the upper boundary of an array which you haven't set yet.

Your code won't work as is in any case since you are not passing `lableList_02` in and out of the function - it's local in scope to the function itself.  You would need to pass in `oFormPage`, update `oFormPage` within the function and pass it back out again.

Something like this will work, but you would either need to pass in and out two arrays to have the two options for your `CC` case or drop that to a single array output.

```
Dim oFormPage
Call GEN_FormLabelCheck("CC", oFormPage) 
MsgBox UBound(oFormPage)

Function GEN_FormLabelCheck(oModuleName,oFormPage)

        Select Case oModuleName
            Case "AA"
                oFormPage=split("Scenario|Name|Event,"|")
            Case "BB"
                oFormPage=split("ID|Issue|mandatory?,"|")
            Case "CC"
                oFormPage=split("Work|Category|Type","|")
        End Select
End Function
```

And in this case, where you are able to define the values, you would be as well defining them as an array anyway rather than using `split`:
    oFormPage = Array("Work", "Category", "Type")

You should consider handling the case where the input doesn't match anything in your `Select Case` statement and as a result `oFormPage` doesn't come out of the function as an array, which would once again give you the type mismatch error.

Let me know if you need any further explanation?